# Transfer files from iphone to PC through USB using Phonegap

Tags: cordova, ipad

how do I transfer files captured through iPad  to my computer using phonegap?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554886/how-do-you-export-a-file-out-of-ios-when-using-cordova-file-plugin/31555890#31555890